# 405 Method Not Allowed on /oauth/token endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I'm getting this strange error when I try to use my client_credentials authentication.
I'm saying strange because POST is the default method and the authentication pass, so the error does not have sense.

Will appreciate some idea of what might be happening!

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    /**
     * Setting web authentication for the resource server
     */
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Enabling security by expressions
     */
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    protected static class GlobalMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
            return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Configuring the authorization server
     */
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        public static final String CLIENT_ID = "...";
        public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "....";

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(this.tokenStore).authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                .scopes("read", "write");
        }

    }

}
```

And the web security:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PingController.ENDPOINT).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

Here is the log of the request (which seems to pass fine I think):

```
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/css/**'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/js/**'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/images/**'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/error'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3af64cd3
2016-10-03 08:02:58.391 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.392 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.392 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.393 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'frxiBDhlaDpxulFzm5dp7Ax0jt'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.394 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-10-03 08:02:58.399 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : Looking for Pre/Post annotations for method 'loadClientByClientId' on target class 'class org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.InMemoryClientDetailsService'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.399 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : No expression annotations found
2016-10-03 08:02:58.399 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : Looking for Pre/Post annotations for method 'setClientDetailsStore' on target class 'class org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.InMemoryClientDetailsService'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.399 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : No expression annotations found
2016-10-03 08:02:58.399 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : Looking for Pre/Post annotations for method 'loadClientByClientId' on target class 'class org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.InMemoryClientDetailsService'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.399 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource : No expression annotations found
2016-10-03 08:02:58.402 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@820d5399: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@7df21f39: Username: frxiBDhlaDpxulFzm5dp7Ax0jt; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities
2016-10-03 08:02:58.402 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.402 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.402 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.402 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@820d5399: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@7df21f39: Username: frxiBDhlaDpxulFzm5dp7Ax0jt; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.402 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@e037fe8
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@820d5399: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@7df21f39: Username: frxiBDhlaDpxulFzm5dp7Ax0jt; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@697acb2a, returned: 1
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-10-03 08:02:58.403 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-10-03 08:02:58.405 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@e7e2eeb]]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.405 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/gynto-api-1.0/oauth/token]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.405 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@27fb8477] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.406 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
2016-10-03 08:02:58.412 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
2016-10-03 08:02:58.412 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
2016-10-03 08:02:58.412 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
2016-10-03 08:02:58.413  WARN 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
2016-10-03 08:02:58.413 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-10-03 08:02:58.413 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Cleared thread-bound request context: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@e7e2eeb]]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.413 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-10-03 08:02:58.414 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-10-03 08:02:58.414 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/css/**'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/js/**'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/images/**'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/error'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error has an empty filter list
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@ada3202]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/gynto-api-1.0/error]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@27fb8477] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-10-03 08:02:58.416 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2016-10-03 08:02:58.418 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Found 2 matching mapping(s) for [/error] : [{[/error]}, {[/error],produces=[text/html]}]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.418 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.419 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@56bcbf0a]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.422 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Skip CORS processing: response already contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header
2016-10-03 08:02:58.432 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver@57fd3677] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.433 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver@6ec69ff3] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.433 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver@773d7e4] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.433 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@541b02b6] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.433 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMethodArgumentResolver@4dce3326] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.433 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MatrixVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver@a836d1d] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.434 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor@36e83868] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.434 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@2b62f056] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.434 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver@4543cc5d] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.434 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver@799f74e3] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.434 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver@608a10d4] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.434 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver@62b0584a] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.434 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolver@51948439] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.434 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] s.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite : Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver@3186e449] supports [interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.435 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Invoking [BasicErrorController.error] method with arguments [FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@ada3202]]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.435 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Method [error] returned [<405 Method Not Allowed,{timestamp=Mon Oct 03 08:02:58 UYT 2016, status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, exception=org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, message=Request method 'POST' not supported, path=/gynto-api-1.0/oauth/token},{}>]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.450 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Mon Oct 03 08:02:58 UYT 2016, status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, exception=org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, message=Request method 'POST' not supported, path=/gynto-api-1.0/oauth/token}] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@6d3b37cf]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.450 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-10-03 08:02:58.450 TRACE 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Cleared thread-bound request context: FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@ada3202]
2016-10-03 08:02:58.450 DEBUG 48084 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG guys, I had another controller accidentally mapping the endpoint.
This was the problem. It is Embarrassing :)

Comment: HI ,  Faced the same problems you solved it here  and it drives me crazy, below is the error  would you help? Written [ m ethod Not Allowed, exception=org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, message=Request method 'POST' not supported, path=/oauth/token}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@69dc7b24]